# How to pass data from 2nd activity to 1st (Popup) without press back button and close button?

Tags: android

I want to call data of activity using popup. Let me explain in brief... when i click on EditText of a dialog box [image: Dailogbox]

when i click on EditText (Template) then it will open activity. [image: Activity, when i click on EditText(Template)]

after i select one option and activity will finish and selected option's value will be set in EditText of Template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use a Button (perhaps with a drawable) instead of an EditText? This makes more sense because the user won't be typing anything into the EditText.

As for passing the data back and forth, [just use startActivityForResult()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10407371/7434090).

[image: Before choosing template]

[image: After choosing template]

Comment: it's working in activity but it's not working in AlertDialog case.

Comment: You could [use an AlertDialog.Builder](https://medium.com/@suragch/creating-a-custom-alertdialog-bae919d2efa5) and put it right in your Activity code. Then `startActivityforResult()` would work find because you're still in the Activity.